# Retrieve Rails Records Using Angular $resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-resource

I am trying to retrieve a collection of rails records using angular's $resource however when I try to render those records in the view I keep getting an empty array.

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @posts = current_user.author.posts.limit(25)
end
```

**app.js.coffee**

```
app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])

app.factory 'Posts', ($resource) ->
  $resource '/posts/:id', {}, query:
    method: 'GET'
    isArray: true
    responseType: 'json'

app.controller 'PostsCtrl', ($scope, Posts) ->
  $scope.posts = Posts.query()
```

In the console I see the $resolved is false so I am unsure whether the issue has to do with accessing the json data itself or with $promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes a bit to get your head around asynchronous programming, coming from a language like Ruby that lacks Async.

You need to pass in a callback to the query() method. So your example should look like (in JS):

```
Posts.query(function(posts) {
    $scope.posts = posts;
})
```

**On a side note:** It is a best practice to post your example Angular code in JavaScript -- unless the question is specific to CoffeeScript.

Comment: Got it. $resolved is now true but is still returning an empty array. So it seems the root issue is $resource is not properly accessing my rails records. What is the best approach to troubleshooting this?

Comment: Use the developer tools in your browser to confirm your hypothesis. You should be able to see the request and response. In Chrome dev tools go to Network, select the filter and select Ajax.

Comment: Yup got it to work, had to change how I was getting the records in the (rails) controller